# Dynamically change a status bar icon in an IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ IDEA plugin that adds an icon to the status bar.

How can I change the icon dinamycally? I am using `StatusBarWidget` and `StatusBar.addWidget()` to add the widget to the status bar, with a `StatusBarWidget.IconPresentation`.

The only thing I could find is this http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5522935 but it only applies to `AnAction`, not a `StatusBarWidget` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `com.intellij.openapi.wm.StatusBarWidget.IconPresentation#getIcon` to return an icon dynamically, you may look into IntelliJ sources for an inspiration. You may also need to call `com.intellij.openapi.wm.StatusBar#updateWidget`